# number of rows contained in existing section after update (15) must equal

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So i'm building an app as a hobby and have researched, it appears a few people have a similar problem, except mine happens when inserting the data to begin with. So I think it's slightly different.

When I go to insert data into my array and table it returns an error (title), it retrieves the right amount of current count, but struggled to add a new one.

```
class AccountsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview2: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Set the table background as the image
        tableview.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "splasnowords-1.png"))

        //Use the edit button item provided by the table view controller
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
        //self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

        //Calculate the latest totalstandings
        BudgetDataModel.calculateTotalStandings()
        totalLabel.text = ("Total Current Standings = £\(BudgetDataModel.returnTrueValue(number: BudgetDataModel.total))")

        self.tableview.delegate = self
        self.tableview2.delegate = self
        self.tableview.dataSource = self
        self.tableview2.dataSource = self
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if (tableView == tableview){
        return 1
            //BudgetDataModel.budgets.count
        }
        else{
            return 2
                //SavingsDataModel.savings.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{
        //reload data?
        if (tableView == tableview){
            return "Budgets"
        }
        else{
            return "Savings"
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var rowCount = 0
        if (tableView == self.tableview) {
            rowCount = BudgetDataModel.budgets.count
        }
        if (tableView == self.tableview2) {
            rowCount = SavingsDataModel.savings.count
        }
        return rowCount

        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       //Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
        if (tableView == self.tableview){
            let cellIdentifier = "AccountsTableViewCell"
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AccountsTableViewCell

            let budget = BudgetDataModel.budgets[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

            cell.nameLabel.text = budget.name
            cell.amountLabel.text = ("£\(BudgetDataModel.returnTrueValue(number: budget.amount))")
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
            return cell
        }
        else if (tableView == self.tableview2){
            let cellIdentifier = "SavingsTableViewCell"
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SavingsTableViewCell
            let saving = SavingsDataModel.savings[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

            cell.savingsnameLabel.text = saving.savingname
            cell.savingsamountLabel.text = ("£\(BudgetDataModel.returnTrueValue(number: saving.savingamount))")
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
            return cell
         }
        else { preconditionFailure ("unexpected cell type") }
    }

    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            if (tableView == tableview){
                // Delete the row from the data source
                BudgetDataModel.budgets.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                BudgetDataModel.saveBudgets()
                BudgetDataModel.calculateTotalStandings()
                totalLabel.text = ("Total Current Standings = £\(BudgetDataModel.returnTrueValue(number:BudgetDataModel.total))")
               // self.tableview.reloadData()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

            }
            else if (tableView == tableview2){
                // Delete the row from the data source
                SavingsDataModel.savings.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                SavingsDataModel.saveSavings()
                //implement   BudgetDataModel.calculateTotalStandings()
                //implement   totalLabel.text = ("Total Current Standings = £\(BudgetDataModel.returnTrueValue(number:BudgetDataModel.total))")
                //self.tableview2.reloadData()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

            }
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }

    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail"{
            let budgetDetailViewController = segue.destination as! BudgetViewController
            //Get the cell that generated this segue.
            if let selectedBudgetCell = sender as? AccountsTableViewCell {
                let indexPath = tableview.indexPath(for: selectedBudgetCell)!
                let selectedBudget = BudgetDataModel.budgets[indexPath.row]
                budgetDetailViewController.budget = selectedBudget
            }
        }
        else if segue.identifier == "AddItem"{
            //self.tableview.reloadData()
            print("Adding new budget.")
        }
        else if segue.identifier == "ShowSavings"{
                let savingDetailViewController = segue.destination as! SavingsViewController
                //Get the cell that generated this segue.
                if let selectedSavingsCell = sender as? SavingsTableViewCell {
                    let indexPath = tableview2.indexPath(for: selectedSavingsCell)!
                    let selectedSavings = SavingsDataModel.savings[indexPath.row]
                    savingDetailViewController.saving = selectedSavings
                }
        }
        else if segue.identifier == "AddSaving"{
            //self.tableview2.reloadData()
            print ("Adding new saving.")
        }
    }

    //MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func unwindToBudgetList(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
        if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? BudgetViewController, let budget = sourceViewController.budget {
            if let selectedIndexPath = tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow{
                //Update an existing budget.
                BudgetDataModel.budgets[selectedIndexPath.row] = budget
                tableview.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
            }
            else{
                    //Add a new budget
                    let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row:BudgetDataModel.budgets.count, section: 0)
                    BudgetDataModel.budgets.append(budget)
                    tableview.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .bottom)
                }
            //Save the budgets.
            BudgetDataModel.saveBudgets()
            BudgetDataModel.calculateTotalStandings()
            totalLabel.text = ("Total Current Standings = £\(BudgetDataModel.returnTrueValue(number: BudgetDataModel.total))")

        }
    }

    @IBAction func unwindtoSavingsList(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
        if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? SavingsViewController, let savings = sourceViewController.saving {
            if let selectedIndexPath = tableview2.indexPathForSelectedRow{
                //Update an existing budget.
                SavingsDataModel.savings[selectedIndexPath.row] = savings
                tableview2.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
            }
            else{
                //Add a new saving
                let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row:SavingsDataModel.savings.count, section: 1)
                SavingsDataModel.savings.append(savings)
                //tableview2.reloadData()
                tableview2.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .bottom)
            }
            //Save the budgets.
            SavingsDataModel.saveSavings()
            //implement    SavingsDataModel.calculateTotalStandings()
            //    totalLabel.text = ("Total Current Standings = £\(BudgetDataModel.returnTrueValue(number: BudgetDataModel.total))")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It breaks at IBAction fund unwindSavingsList

On the tableview2.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .bottom)

Comment: You are aware that your second table has two identical sections, right?

Comment: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (15) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (14), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: @jcaron where is this declared? In the number of sections area? If i return just 1 it gives me an error of attempt to insert row 14 into section 1, but there are only 1 sections after the update'

Comment: Sections and rows are 0-based, so you should be using `section: 0`.

Comment: Only problem it brings now, is that the second table doesn't actually load on the view. Only the first table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @jcaron

Two corrections required:

1. Change my numberofsectionscode to return 1, so that my second table didn't have a randomly replicated second section

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

2. Replace the section with 0, when adding a new saving

//Add a new saving
                let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row:SavingsDataModel.savings.count, section: 1)